# Get radio status from Android?

Tags: android, networking

Is there a way to check the current status of the cell radio in Android? I've been learning about the way that the radio powers up and down for transmissions, and I'm slightly horrified at the way I've been writing my apps. Is there a way to check whether the radio's powered up already (allowing me to piggyback on the session and save data) or to receive an event when the radio powers up?

Comment: Are you looking for something more than http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html will give you? You can register a receiver that notifies you of data, network, phone availability.

Comment: Please look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5onKZcJyJwI) video. It will not help you listen events of radio hardware but it will help you to build architecture of your application in more efficient way (batch and bundle data transfers).